# File from POST Request to MIMEBase

Tags: python, email

I'm currently trying to send mails with attachments.

However, I'm currently struggling to convert the file I'm supposed to receive.

Here's my request POST:

```
curl --form "file=@year.txt" http://localhost:8000/
```

I need to know how can I extract the file year.txt from my request, and then convert it to MIMEBase, so I can send it through EmailMessage.

```
file = request.POST.get('file')
email = EmailMessage(
    subject,
    content,
    None,
    ['random@example.com'],
)
email.attach_file(file)
```

That'd be something like this; however, I'm not sure the process to follow. That's why I require your help.

Comment: Please don't invent email addresses in existing domains to use as placeholders; the owner of that address will start receiving spam when a spammer scrapes this page. I have edited to use `example.com` instead, which exists precisely for this purpose, and will never host actual mailboxes, web pages, or etc.

Answer (score 0):

`EmailMessage` does not support passing in the Subject etc. as arguments. Instead, you need something like

```
from email.message import EmailMessage

email = EmailMessage()
email["subject"] = subject
email["from"] = "you@example.org"  # you need to pass in a sender too
email["to"] = "random@example.com"
email.set_content(content)
email.add_attachment(file, maintype="application", subtype="octet-stream")
```

If you have a more specific MIME type to use than the generic `application/octet-stream`, by all means use that instead. In this particular case, I guess `text/plain` would be correct and useful, but of course, that might not be applicable more generally, and really depends on your use case and application design.

See the [examples from the `email` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html) for variations and details.

Getting the generated message off your system is a separate topic which is often hard for beginners. If you run this in a place where you have an outgoing email server in the local network which doesn't require authentication, you should be able to simply create an `smtplib.SMTP` object and pass the message to its `send_message` method, but many real-world deployments have complications like requiring to authenticate to a remote server. There are, of course, many existing questions about that here, so please search before you ask a new question.